# implication of using additional loop

Tags: python

I have script `A`:

```
...
cursor.execute('SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableA')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    statement = 'INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)'
    args = row.col1, row.col2
    cursor.execute(statement, args)
```

And script `B`:

```
...
columns = []
cursor.execute('SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableA')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    column_object = [row.col1, row.col2]
    columns.append(column_object)

for column_object in columns:
    statement = 'INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)'
    args = column_object[0], column_object[1]
    cursor.execute(statement, args)
```

Using a small sample test set, I ran both scripts 5 times and the performance is negligible.  Is one method preferred over the other?

Comment: Don't manually insert text into queries. That's how SQL injection happens.

Comment: Why are you not using parametrized queries?

Comment: @Blender This is an internal maintenance script.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO bad practices == bad practices ... internal-use or not ;-P

Comment: After using parameters, are there any implications of using one method over another?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: SQL injection isn't always intentional and the fix is trivial, so there's no reason not to.

Comment: `cursor.executemany(...)` might save you some time as well

Comment: @Hoopdady That's assuming that I load the values into a list.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying it might be a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Script A uses less memory, and is shorter and simpler. So I would use A.

You could address the memory issue in B by turning the building of columns into a generator, but it would still be more complex than A.

Comment: Since the result of the cursor (`cursor.fetchall()`) is stored in `rows`, I'm assuming the loop will not be interrupted when a new statement is executed using the cursor?